# Make a colored ListPlot

Tags: color, plotting

Basically I have a set of 3D points, such as {3,4,3} or {4,1,4}. Instead of plotting the points in a 3D space, I want to plot the x,y coordinates of the points on the 2D plane and use the z coordinate to define a color for that point. So the color will be different depending on the z coordinate. I've tried a lot of things and haven't had any luck. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

**ListPlot**

```
data = RandomInteger[10, {10, 3}];
sdata = Style[{#, #2}, PointSize[.05], 
     ColorData[{"Rainbow", Through@{Min, Max}@data[[All, -1]]}][#3]] & @@@ data;

ListPlot[sdata, PlotRangePadding -> 3]
```

[image]

Or

```
ListPlot[List /@ data[[All, ;; 2]], PlotRangePadding -> 3, 
 BaseStyle -> PointSize[.05], 
 PlotStyle -> (ColorData[{"Rainbow", 
      Through@{Min, Max}@data[[All, -1]]}] /@ data[[All, -1]])]
(* same picture as above *)
```

**BubbleChart**

```
sdata2 = Style[Labeled[{#, #2, 1}, #3, Center],
     Directive[PointSize[.05],
      ColorData[{"Rainbow", Through@{Min, Max}@data[[All, -1]]}][#3]]] & @@@ data;

BubbleChart[sdata2]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

One way is just to build it up from primitives. Here is some data:

```
SeedRandom[123];
data = RandomReal[{1, 10}, {10, 3}];
```

rescale the z values:

```
data[[All, 3]] = Rescale[data[[All, 3]], {1, 10}];
```

or rescale over min and max of the z values etc -- up to you. Then plot:

```
Graphics[{AbsolutePointSize[15], 
  MapThread[{Hue[#3], Point[{#1, #2}]} &, Transpose[data]]},
 AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio,
 Frame -> True]
```

[image]